Как правильно с окончанием:
Шкаф в стиле классицизм (или классицизма)?

Все хорошо, но не очень ясно, что такое стиль "классицизм" у шкафа), классицизм - это направление музыки, живописи, скульптуры и архитектуры, но не дизайна вещей, как мне кажется). То есть классицизм соприкасается с духовной сферой, а не бытовой. А шкаф - в классическом стиле, в стиле барокко, в стиле модерн, возможно...


Ответы Справочной службы:
№ 262139.
Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно
(работают, выполнены, скульптура,...) в стиле классицизм 
или в стиле классицизма. Заранее спасибо. ОТВЕТ. 
Корректно: в стиле классицизм.



Однако в другом ответе: Дело не в норме, а в языковом вкусе авторов словарей и носителей языка. Конечно, Вы можете руководствоваться и рекомендацией БТС.

Карта слов  (чаще: в стиле классицизма)
Давайте рассмотрим сохранившиеся постройки в стиле 
классицизма.Елена Крижевская, Москва изнутри. Роскошные 
интерьеры и архитектурные истории, 2020

За деревянным тамбуром спряталась печь в стиле 
классицизм, финского производства, а сразу за ней 
начинается любопытнейшая прямоугольная лестница. 
Владислав Пода, Где бьется сердце Петербурга? Доходные 
дома в историях и фотографиях, 2021


Как правильно?  Управление Р.п. представляется более точной и книжной формой, а  отсутствие управления ближе к разговорной речи.



Спасибо! А почему вам именно так представляются книжный и разговорный варианты?

В сочетании "стиль классицизм" слово "классицизм" является приложением. Приложение должно согласоваться с существительным в падеже,  но здесь нет согласования (в стиле классицизм). Поэтому  это не точная грамматическая форма,  а правильной формой  является управление Р. п.

Как вы думаете, почему на Грамоте выбрали разговорный вариант в качестве корректного ответа?

Трудно сказать) Вероятно, у отвечающего такой языковой вкус)  Я была удивлена таким ответом, если сравнивать его с практикой существующего письма. // К другим вариантам они относятся тоже положительно. // Другая версия: может ошиблись в 2010 году, а ошибки они не признают.

В Национальном корпусе русского языка:
в стиле классицизма — 29 примеров;
в стиле классицизм — 0 примеров.
